# Navigating to new page with global object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building Html web site...
After filling my form on `page1.html`, I want to save all the fields in a global object, and navigate to another page - `page2.html`.
In `page2.html` I thought get those params.

I created button for navigation:

```
<a href= "page2.html"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit1" value="Go"  /> </a>
```

And added the function to the end of `page1.html`:

```
<script>
    $("#submit1").click(function () {
   shareObject = new Object();
   shareObject.name = $("#name").val();
   shareObject.email = $("#email").val();
   shareObject.phone = $("#phone").val();
   shareObject.address= $("#address").val();

    window.shareObject = shareObject; 
    });
</script
```

I was thinking in `page2.html` to get those values by properties of the shared Object -  `shareObject`, for example:

```
alert (shareObject.name);
```

But the `page2.html` does not recognize `shareObject`.

Any ideas why? or maybe ideas how better implementing it?

Comment: If you already have a form in the first page, which call the second page; why do you want to access some variables in an other way than `$_POST[...]` or `$_GET[...]`

Comment: its a new dom in the new page..so the values can not be shared like u did..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible using the way you want, but using following ways you can do it.

1. HTML5 localStorage use: localStorage.setItem() & getItem()
2. HTML5 sessionStorage same as above.
3. Local cookies. window.cookie
4. HTML5 websql http://slides.html5rocks.com/

Comment: So what about all the global parameters if you can't save them for different pages?

Comment: you can serialize all global parameters & save & get back on different page using all above HTML5 options. if you are not using html5 then ajax or server side session handling will be the best way to do it.

Comment: Is it safe using html5 storage for passing prices and stuff like that...cant the user change it?

Comment: I was not aware that you are using it for a app like shopping cart. for this kind of app you MUST use sessions on server side. may be some info like favorite products can be stored in localstorage to serve customer better.

Comment: all the payment done in server, I want to use local storage only for displaying it before the checkout. What you mean by sessions on server?

Comment: tried it...I see it save it to local storage but as navigating to page2 I see that local storage is empty.

Answer (score 0):

When the page reloads, all JavaScript variables reset. If your site is static, you should use [ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) to update page partially, else if your website is dynamic you can pass this variable to server and render new page with this new variable

Answer (score 0):

> maybe ideas how better implementing it?

Why do you need to navigate to a different page? why not just toggle the different parts of the form in and out of view?

Comment: The reason is that I navigating to a shopping cart page,and some of the parameters form are from page1 and other from others pages.